# How can I correctly use RxJS to add a new field to each object of an array returned into an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am not so into RxJS and I ahve the following doubt.

Into this an Angular service class I have this method retrieving data from Firebase FireStore database:

```
async getAllEmployees() { 
    return <Observable<User[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('profileType', '!=', 'admin')).valueChanges();          
  }
```

As you can see it is returning an Observable of **User** object.

where **User** is this interface:

```
export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    surname: string;   
    completeName: string;  
    email: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    companyName: string;
    vatID: string;
    profileType: 'admin' | 'user' | 'unknown';    
    UID: string;    
    approved:boolean;
}
```

Now I need to add the **completeName** field (not presented on Firestore, so this field is not retrieved) that is the concatenation of the **firstName** and the **surname** field to each object of the retrieved array of the returned Observable. I am thinking that maybe I can use RxJS map operator to achieve this task. I was trying to do something like this:

```
return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)).valueChanges()
                                              .pipe(map(userObj => {

                                                        const completeObj = {
                                                          completeName = userObj["firstName"] + " " + userObj["surname"],
                                                          ...userObj
                                                        }
                                                        console.log("completeObj: ", completeObj);
                                                        return userObj;
                                                    }));
```

But doing in this way I obtain that it is created the following object (I can see it in the console.log into my Chrome console):

```
completeObj:  
{0: {…}, completeName: "undefined undefined"}
0: {firstName: "Andrea", isEmployee: true, socialSecurityCode: "NBLNDRH501O", password: "XXXXXX", isAdmin: false, …}
completeName: "undefined undefined"
__proto__: Object
```

So basically it seems to me that it is not adding this new calculated field to each object of the array returned as Observable but it is adding to the Observable itself.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing?  How can I fix it?

Comment: try `{completeName:  userObj["firstName"] + " " + userObj["surname"], ...userObj}`

Comment: @TheHeadRush returning this object? is it now working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `userObj` is an Array of employees. The rxjs operator map maps this array, not the array elements. What you need is a "nested" map.

```
return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true))
  .valueChanges().pipe(
    map(usersArr => usersArr.map(user => ({ ...user, completeName: user.firstName + " " user.surname}))),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a property via assignment.

This is an object:

```
{
  firstName: "Hillary",
  lastName: "Brown"
}
```

and this is not valid syntax:

```
{
  firstName = "Hillary",
  lastName = "Brown"
}
```

I'm surprised what you did compile. Maybe it's doing something strange with the current context (this)? I  just tried doing something similar and that wouldn't compile for me.

Also, your map returns the same value it gets in, you probably want to return the new object.

```
return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection(
  'users',
  ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)
).valueChanges().pipe(
  map(userObj => ({
    ...userObj,
    completeName: userObj["firstName"] + " " + userObj["surname"]
  })),
  tap(completeObj => console.log("completeObj: ", completeObj))
);
```